# Merge Sorted Array, issue while removing a certain item

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

You are given two integer arrays `nums1` and `nums2`, sorted in non-decreasing order, and two integers m and n, representing the number of elements in nums1 and nums2 respectively.

Merge `nums1` and `nums2` into a single array sorted in non-decreasing order.

The final sorted array should not be returned by the function, but instead, be stored inside the array `nums1`. To accommodate this, `nums1` has a length of `m + n`, where the first `m` elements denote the elements that should be merged, and the last `n` elements are set to 0 and should be ignored. `nums2` has a length of `n`.

```
nums1 = [-1,0,0,3,3,3,0,0,0]
nums2 = [1,2,2]
m = 6
n = 3
```

I coded it like this,

```
class Solution:
    def merge(self, nums1: List[int], m: int, nums2: List[int], n: int) -> None:
        numsa = nums1
        numsb = nums2

        for i in range(len(numsa)):
            if nums1[-1]==0:
                nums1.remove(nums1[-1])

        for i in range(len(numsb)):
            if nums2[-1]==0:
                nums2.remove(nums2[-1])

        nums1+=nums2
        nums1=nums1.sort()
```

but while removing the 0s from the end in nums1, it is also removing the 0s from the middle. I am not sure why that is happening and would appreciate some help with the same.

Comment: Are you sure you're allowed to use `list.sort` in this exercise?

Comment: I'm guessing you weren't meant to use `remove` at all. Otherwise there would have been no point in leaving extra members in the first list.

Comment: Hey, there were no restrictions in using the list.sort(), I used pop instead of remove, and it worked for me.